# Prove that $\mu \times \lambda$ is a measure on $\mathcal{S} \times \mathcal{T}.$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{S}, \mu)$ and $(Y, \mathcal{T}, \lambda)$ be $\sigma$-finite measure spaces. If $Q \in \mathcal{S} \times \mathcal{T}$  we define $$\mu \times \lambda(Q) = \int_{X} \lambda(Q_{x})d\mu(x) = \int_{Y}\mu(Q^y)d\lambda(y).$$ Prove that $\mu \times \lambda$ is a measure on $\mathcal{S} \times \mathcal{T}.$

Could anyone give me an idea of how to use the given 2 equalities in the proof?

Also, I found this question here [Measurability of product measures $ \{\mu \in M: (\mu \times \mu)(A) \in B\} \in \mathscr{M}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1678329/measurability-of-product-measures-mu-in-m-mu-times-mua-in-b-in) is the solution of the given question similar to the solution of this question.

**Note:** I am studying from Royden and Fitzpatrick "Real Analysis" fourth edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Show and use that for $(E_n)_{n\geq 1}\subseteq \mathcal{S}\times \mathcal{T}$ one has
$$
\Big(\bigcup_{n\geq 1} E_n\Big)_x=\bigcup_{n\geq 1}(E_n)_x
$$

Comment: oh, if this is the case it is easy but how to show this in terms of the given 2 equations ... could you provide details, please?

Comment: @Emptymind: Well, there's not really much to show. The LHS is $\{y\in Y\mid (x,y)\in \bigcup_{n\geq 1}E_n\}$ whereas the RHS is $\bigcup_{n\geq 1}\{y\in Y\mid (x,y)\in E_n\}$. It should be fairly obvious that they're the same set.

Comment: so how you will use the given equations in the 2nd line?

Comment: Tell me exactly what you're trying to show and where you're stuck.

Comment: Ok I will edit my question with my trials within 8 hours(just because I have to go to my job now) to show you my work